# How to go back to previous screen if an action failed in install4j

Tags: install4j

If an action failed, in failure strategy there is an option "Ask user weather to retry or quit on failure". If user selects retry option it is retrying the same action and failing again.

In my case, if user selects retry option, user need to go back to previous screen change the selections and retry.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **install4j 6**, just set the "Failure strategy" property of the action to "Return to parent screen".

In  **install4j 5 and earlier**, you have to add a "Run script" action with the script:

```
if (context.isErrorOccurred()) {
    Util.showWarningMessage("Action failed");
    context.goBack(0);
}
return true;
```

and, additionally, insert a "Run script" action with the script:

```
context.setErrorOccurred(false);
return true;
```

before the action whose failure you want to check.